# Can I select a node but not check/uncheck it in jsTree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I want to select node in jsTree by click on title. Node should not change it checked state.

I read [jsTree checkbox plugin documentation](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=$.jstree.defaults.checkbox&f=$.jstree.defaults.checkbox), but have not found about this.
[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. Use the `tie_selection` checkbox config option when creating the tree:

```
$('#tree').jstree({
  checkbox : {
    tie_selection : false,
    ...
```

I would recommend reading about the other checkbox options in the API docs on jstree.com, as you might want to tweak those too (like `whole_node : false`).

Best regards,
Ivan